# On console, comparing items on guild store or vendor, possible to compare to backup weapon or ring 2?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When browsing items on the guild store, and while levelling, on a vendor, is it possible to compare the item being looked at to your backup weapon, or ring #2?

For instance, my Templar has a bow as primary weapon, and a healing staff as my backup weapon (second weapon set).

Inside the menus when I'm looking at things like skills and such I can switch between primary and backup weapon sets and skillbars using the Y button (Xbox One).

However, on the guild store, if I'm looking at a healing staff, it is being compared to my primary weapon, my bow. Is there any way for me to switch to comparing with the backup weapon, other than going into inventory and switching weapons around so that my healing staff is primary?

This same thing happens when looking at rings, it compares the ring being looked at to ring #1. Is it possible, other than switching the rings around in my inventory, to get it to compare to ring #2 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the UI and found no such functions. Comparison works for every peace of quipment the same, one to one.

So from empirical evidence I'd say there's no way.

Comment: Since this seems to be the correct answer I will accept it, wish it wasn't though :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I could give that answer several days ago but was waiting on positive answer with the same hope =)